# Memory leak in Midas depthmap computation?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, memory-leaks

I'm using Midas very like in [Huggingface's demo](https://huggingface.co/spaces/akhaliq/DPT-Large).

My issue is that the RAM usage increase at each depth map computation.

Here is the full code.

```
#!venv/bin/python3

from pathlib import Path
import psutil

import numpy as np
import torch
import cv2


def make_model():
    model_type = "DPT_BEiT_L_512"       # MiDaS v3.1 - Large
    midas = torch.hub.load("intel-isl/MiDaS", model_type)

    device = torch.device("cuda")
    midas.to(device)
    midas.eval()

    midas_transforms = torch.hub.load("intel-isl/MiDaS", "transforms")

    transform = midas_transforms.dpt_transform

    return {"transform": transform,
            "device": device,
            "midas": midas
            }


def inference(cv_image, model):
    """Make the inference."""
    transform = model['transform']
    device = model["device"]
    midas = model["midas"]

    input_batch = transform(cv_image).to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        prediction = midas(input_batch)

        prediction = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(
            prediction.unsqueeze(1),
            size=cv_image.shape[:2],
            mode="bilinear",
            align_corners=False,
        ).squeeze()

    output = prediction.cpu().numpy()
    formatted = (output * 255 / np.max(output)).astype('uint8')

    return formatted


# Create Midas "DPT_BEiT_L_512" -  MiDaS v3.1 - Large
model = make_model()

image_dir = Path('.') / "all_images"

for image_file in image_dir.iterdir():
    ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
    print("image", ram_usage)
    cv_image = cv2.imread(str(image_file))
    _ = inference(cv_image, model)
```

In short:

- Create the model "DPT_BEiT_L_512"
- Define the function `inference`
- loop over the images in the directory `all_images`
- for each: `cv2.imread`
- compute the depthmap (do not keep the result in memory)

I see that the RAM usage keeps raising over and over.

Variation:
I've tried to read only one image (so only one `cv2.imread`) and, in the loop, only add a random noise on that image. Up to random noise, the inference function always receive the same image.
In that case, the RAM usage is stable.

QUESTIONS:

- Where does the memory leak come from ?
- Do I have to "reset" something between two inferences ?

EDIT some variations

variation 1: always the same image
replace the `iterdir` loop by this:

```
cv_image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
for i in range(1, 100):
    ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
    print(i, ram_usage)
    _ = get_depthmap(cv_image, model)
```

Here you get no memory leak.

Variation 2: do not compute the depth map

```
for image_file in image_dir.iterdir():
    ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
    print("image", ram_usage)
    cv_image = cv2.imread(str(image_file))
    # _ = get_depthmap(cv_image, model)
```

The memory leak does not occurs.

I deduce that `cv2.imread` itself does not makes the leak.

Variation 3: same image, random noise:

```
cv_image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
for i in range(1, 100):
    ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
    print(i, ram_usage)

    noise = np.random.randn(
        cv_image.shape[0], cv_image.shape[1], cv_image.shape[2]) * 20
    noisy_img = cv_image + noise
    noisy_img = np.clip(noisy_img, 0, 255)

    _ = get_depthmap(noisy_img, model)
```

No leak in this version.

Comment: so... you're saying repeated calls to `cv2.imread()` cause arbitrarily growing RAM usage? please show the code where you call `cv2.imread()` just once

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Question edited. I added some variations: always the same image, always the same image with random noise, and not computing the depth map.

Comment: ok... but did you have a version where `inference()` is called repeatedly, and memory grows infinitely, but imread is called just once? or does this, for some reason, require imread() in the loop, to be growing infinitely?

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz If I call `imread` only once, I always send the same image to `inference`. And the I have no leak. This is the reason why I tried with the random noise: this version uses `imread` only once but send slightly different images to `inference`.

Comment: and when you generate variants with random noise (and feed to inference), does that provoke growing memory use? I'm sorry I have to ask. I'm just peeking in here during idle time, not keeping track of everything. the part of your question talking about using random noise isn't clear to me as to whether that does or does not provoke growing memory usage.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz   Same image + random noise -> no memory leak.  The only memory leak I found is when I'm inferring "completely" different images

Comment: fascinating. could you attempt to "copy" using `cv.cvtColor(COLOR_BGR2RGB)` or any other OpenCV function (disregarding how it makes no sense to the DNN)? perhaps something in the way opencv makes numpy arrays causes issues, while creating a new array by adding noise (`+` as numpy operation) creates a differently flavored numpy array

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz  Apply one random rotation at each step is considered as "same image" in the sense that no leak is observed when inferring the same image (up to random rotation) again and again.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find the issue?